# Bind a side key on Intermec CN50 PDA to specific action

Tags: c#, button, .net-cf-3.5, windows-mobile-6.1

I'm developing a Windows Mobile application for Windows Mobile 6.1 using C#, VS2008, .NET CF 3.5.

I want the application to programmaticaly bind the PDA side button to a specific method in my application, so when the user presses this button, the application executes the method.

I need the binding to be globally, which means that is would be applied not in a single form or even the entire application but on the OS level, so as long as the application is running, this key is attached to that action, even if the application is running in the background and another application is running on the foreground.

My hardware is: Intermec CN50 using Windows Mobile 6.1 OS

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Detailed discussion and (possible?) answer found on Intermec ommunity forums: http://community.intermec.com/t5/General-Development-Developer/Capture-and-use-specific-button-in-KeyPad-in-C-app-CN50/td-p/16068